# HTML5 body and footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a webpage which the main body is about 95% in width, So the problem i have is i want the footer to be 100% even though i am aware that the footer is a child of the main body this making the footer an equal width as the body.

[image: Here is an example of my problem]

Is there anyway i can override the footer without having to increase the body to 100% width?

I already attempted to set the footer inside a div but i still haven't been able to come up with a solution to my problem

Comment: I use this tutorial for a great footer: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: If you control the positioning of the footer (ie no CMS) then use Diodeus solution. Otherwise you can use either fixed positioning or widths greater than 100% to compensate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a wrapper that is 100% width. Give your content 95% width, give everything else 100%.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>...</header>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked, the only thing i also had to figure out was that when i did it this way, it would push the content to the left making a margin in the right to about 20% of the page and all i did is set margin left and right to 10% in order for it to look like 95%. You think thats safe to do?

Comment: Sure. I would used pixels and centering with margin:0 auto myself.